# Extreme sum values calculated inside a structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

While I was learning to code in C about structure and pointers, I tried to make a program that calculate grades of students.
I thought it would work from my previous experiences for such calculation without pointers and structure. But with those, it gave me wild results in the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
    The program will scan year, name, score of three different subjects,
    and calculate the sum and the average.
    Three different people (using array) will be taken into account.
*/

struct grade {
    int year;
    char name[20];
    int score[3];
    int total;
    float avg;
};

void main() {
    struct grade p[3];
    char str = 'c';
    char *pstr = NULL;
    int i, j;

    pstr = &str;

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("Year of Admission: ");
        scanf("%d", &p[j].year);

        printf("Name of the Student: ");
        scanf("%s", pstr);
        strcpy(p[j].name, pstr);

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("The score for Subject %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &p[j].score[i]);
            p[j].total += p[j].score[i];
        }

        p[j].avg = p[j].total / 3.0;

    }

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("%s's\n", p[j].name);
        printf("Total score: %d\n", p[j].total);
        printf("Average: %.2f\n", p[j].avg);

    }
}
```

I could have written each of three different subjects as one variable but for an extra "challenge", I made an array inside the structure.

> int score[3];

However, the program only prints out extremely small number -89541694... for both totals and averages.

I assume that this particular line inside a for-loop is a problem.

> scanf("%d", &p[j].score[i]);

But I could not figure out why. I am really new to pointers and still learning them.

I hope for your generous teaching and explanations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `scanf("%s", pstr);` this is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are not initialized with 0, so you just need to zero it before calculating total:

```
p[j].total = 0;
```

before

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("The score for Subject %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &p[j].score[i]);
        p[j].total += p[j].score[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `pstr` a pointer you might wanted to do somehting like this

```
char pstr[30];
```

And accordingly you will `scanf` the string using `scanf("%29s",pstr);` and check it's return value.

To describe the problem a bit - you had a pointer pointing to a `char` which is not capable of holding an input characters and the corresponding `\0` (nul terminating character). As a result this gives rise to undefined behavior. And then using it in `strcpy` is also an illegal code. (Undefined behavior).

Here the solution I gave simply declared an array of 30 characters and we limited the string input using `scanf` upto 29 characters because we need to store the terminating null.

Showing you atleast a bit of code to make you understand how to write these codes:-

```
if( scanf("%29s",pstr)!= 1){
    fprintf(stderrm"Error in input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Another problem is initialize the variables - here you used `p[j].total += p[j].score[i];` What is the value of `p[j].total` initially. It contains garbage value. In the loop make `p[j].total = 0;` first. That will give you the correct result.

Note: The wild results are the garbage value resulted from addition of some garbage value with `p[j].score[i]`.

Also note that without making the changes that I said if you only change the initialization thing then also code is not **guranteed** to work. undefined behavior is undefined behavior - cases may arise which will simply crash the program making you wonder where you went wrong.

Illustration code may help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
    The program will scan year, name, score of three different subjects,
    and calculate the sum and the average.
    Three different people (using array) will be taken into account.
*/

struct grade {
    int year;
    char name[20];
    int score[3];
    int total;
    float avg;
};

int main(void) {
    struct grade p[3];
    char pstr[20];
    int i, j;


    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("Year of Admission: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &p[j].year)!=1){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Name of the Student: ");
        if(scanf("%19s", pstr)!=1){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(p[j].name, pstr);
        p[j].total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("The score for Subject %d: ", i + 1);
            if(scanf("%d", &p[j].score[i])!=1){
               fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
            }
            if(p[j].score < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            p[j].total += p[j].score[i];
        }

        p[j].avg = p[j].total / 3.0;

    }

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("%s's\n", p[j].name);
        printf("Total score: %d\n", p[j].total);
        printf("Average: %.2f\n", p[j].avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In fact instead of using the `pstr` just input the names directly in the structure variable instance itself. No need to use a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `pstr` points to a single `char`. A string in C needs to be at least *two* characters for a single-character string: The actual character, and the *null terminator*.

When you use e.g. `scanf` to read a string, the function will write at least two bytes to the memory pointed to by `pstr`. But since it only points to a single byte you will write *out of bounds* and that leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to be able to read more than a single character you need to have more space allocated for the string. And you need to limit `scanf` so it will not write out of bounds.

For example

```
char pstr[40];  // Allows for strings up to 39 character, plus terminator

// ...

scanf("%39s", pstr);  // Read at most 39 characters from standard input, and write to pstr
```

---

Another problem is that local variables are not automatically initialized, their values will be *indeterminate*.

That means the contents of the array `p` is unknown and seemingly random.

When you do

```
p[j].total += p[j].score[i];
```

you use the seemingly random value of `p[j].total` to calculate another seemingly random number.

To initialize all structures and all their members to "zero" in the array, do e.g.

```
struct grad p[3] = { 0 };
```